# Add tf-idf values as columns in a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

item = list(df['item1']) + list(df['item2'])
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_sp = tfidf.fit_transform(item)

for i in len(list(df['item1'])):
    new_list =[]
    new_list.append(tfidf.idf_)
df['updated_item'] = list(new_list)
```

I was trying to add the tfidf scores as features. Is it the correct way?

item1 is of shape (400k) and same is the shape of item2.
The shape of tfidf_sp is (800k, 100k).

Comment: Shouldn't you use `tfidf_sp` as your features? Also, have you already done your train-test split?

Comment: If I use new_list.append(tfidf_sp[0:400k]) for item1 and same for item2. My kernel keeps dying.

Comment: Why not just `df['updated_item'] = tfidf.fit_transform(item)`?

Comment: for i in tqdm(list(df['item1'])):                                                                      
     new_list =[]
     new_list.append(tfidf.idf_)
df['updated_item'] = list(new_list)                                                                                  I want to see the progress as well and update them individally

Comment: Can you tell am I making some mistake?

Comment: `for i in tqdm(li`... I have no idea what any of that is supposed to mean I'm afraid.

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: I really have no idea what you're trying to do with that forloop. If you want the tfidf features, I'm pretty sure they are just the output of `tfidf.transform(...)` much like the rest of sklearn

Comment: You are initializing you list inside the for loop...

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(tfidf_sp, columns = tfidf.get_feature_names())
```

This will give you a matrix with the columns as the tfidf vocabulary and each row containing tfidf values corresponding to each item.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Try converting the term-document matrix obtained into an array as follows:

```
tfidf_sp = tfidf.fit_transform(item).toarray()
```

This will solve the Pandas Error.

Comment: This gives an error pandas DataFrame Constructor not properly called